# Installed Ubuntu 18.04 along side Win 10; cannot boot to Win 10 from grub

Tags: boot, dual-boot, uefi, windows-10

I *can* boot to Win 10 if I change the boot order to have the windows partition boot first so it skips grub (so windows is fine, nothing is corrupted there) but when I try to do it from grub (the only Windows related option is **Windows boot manager**, not **Windows 10**) I get to the screen where it displays the windows logo, completes some loading step and then just hangs.

I did a boot-repair and `sudo update-grub` from Ubuntu did not seem to help.
I've checked, both systems are installed in UEFI mode, fast startup and secure boot are both disabled.

Any suggestions (and how can I help you help me)?

Thanks a bunch in advance,

Dejan

P.S.
the machine is a laptop, Asus rog gl502vm, running Windows 10 version 1803 and Ubuntu 18.04

Comment: Could you please run [Boot-Info](//help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Info) and [edit] your question to include a link to its resulting info log? Thanks.

Comment: This sounds like a problem with Windows boot manager Windows is well supported on superuser.com as evidenced by [this related post](https://superuser.com/questions/1314028/what-is-the-relationship-between-windows-boot-manager-and-windows-operating-syst)